# Integral representation of the multinomial coefficient $\binom{N}{k_1, \ldots, k_N}$ subject to the constraint $k_1 + \cdots + k_N = N$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, mellin-transform

Is there a useful integral representation for it? Perhaps through the Fourier or Laplace or Mellin transforms?

Comment: The condition of "useful" has no specific mathematical interpretation. That number is a coefficient of the Taylor of $(x_1+x_2+...+x_N)^N$. Cauchy's integral formula gives the coefficients.